Issues with Running iOS Side of React Native Project on Expo Go
As a student working on a project with React Native, I'm currently using Windows. I've successfully set up and run Android Studio, but I'm having trouble running the iOS side using Expo Go. After scanning the QR code in the Expo Go app on my iPhone, I received the error message: "There was a problem loading the requested app."
How can I resolve this issue?
I tried restarting the Metro Bundler and ensuring that my iPhone was connected to the same Wi-Fi network as my development machine, but the issue persists.

Just a wild guess, are you doing this in your school? perhaps certain ports are blocked within your school network, hence you can't connect your phone. Try doing it at home with your own network.

Have you tried to run your project using tunneling? Maybe Expo Go is missing permissions to access local network or Expo GO version is outdated.
